# Error instantiate a Generic class

Tags: c#, validation, generics

I'm create C# windows application and using FluentValidation for validating a View Model. In every form I always create validation method like this:

```
private bool ValidateCustomer(CustomerViewModel customerVM)
{
    CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
    ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customerVM);

    if (!results.IsValid)
    {
        StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Data Validation Checking Error:\n");

        foreach (var failure in results.Errors)
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine("- " + failure.ErrorMessage);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.ToString(), "Exclamation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerViewModel>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Code).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

I want to create Generic ValidationHelper class so that I don't write the same validation code (just different validator and viewmodel class) in every form, for example:
`ValidationHelper<MyValidator, MyViewModel>.Validate()`. I'm just replace MyValidator and MyViewModel class for the other form. When make this Generic class I'm having problem when instantiate a validator class.

```
public static class ValidatorHelper<T, V> 
        where T : class, new() 
        where V : class, new()
    {
        public static bool Validate(T t, V n)
        {
            T validator = new T(); 
            ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(n); // <--- error on this line

            if (!results.IsValid)
            {
                StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Data Validation Checking Error:\n");

                foreach (var failure in results.Errors)
                {
                    errorMessage.AppendLine("- " + failure.ErrorMessage);
                }

                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.ToString(), "Exclamation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**:

As @JonSkeet and @dbc suggestion, I modified the ValidatorHelper to:

```
public static class ValidatorHelper<T, V>
    where T : AbstractValidator<V>, new()
    where V : class, new()
{
    public static bool Validate(V v)
    {
        T validator = new T();
        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(v);

        if (!results.IsValid)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Data Validation Checking Error:\n");

            foreach (var failure in results.Errors)
            {
                errorMessage.AppendLine("- " + failure.ErrorMessage);
                //log.Message("Property " + failure.PropertyName + " failed validation. Error was: " + failure.ErrorMessage);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.ToString(), "Exclamation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not using T on `public static bool Validate(V v)` because it will be instantiated in it. Then on the form, you've just write:

```
if (ValidatorHelper<CustomerValidator, CustomerViewModel>.Validate(customerVM))
```

Thanks to you both, I can solve the problem, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `public static class ValidatorHelper<T, V> : AbstractValidator<T> ` isn't valid. Static classes can only be inherited from `System.Object`. Fix that, next you can fix `T validator = new CustomerValidator();`

Comment: No, you took me wrong. I didn't asked to remove `AbstractValidator<T>`. It depends upon what you need to do. If you need the base class for your `ValidatorHelper` then you have to remove the `static` modifier.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ok, sorry for misunderstanding, I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your constraints do not indicate that `T` derives from `CustomerValidator`:

```
where T : class, CustomerValidator, new()
```

But what exactly is `CustomerValidator`?  Is it some abstract base class that will be subclassed for each validation requirement?  If so, `new CustomerValidator()` in your old code would not have worked.

If `CustomerValidator` is some newly created abstract base class, you might consider extracting an interface, for clarity, like so:

```
public interface IValidator<V> 
{
    ValidationResult Validate(V data); 
}
```

Basically, this is an interface for a class that validates anything, returning the results in your `ValidationResult` object.

Once you have a standard interface for returning validation results for something, your static helper becomes:

```
public static class ValidatorHelper<T, V> 
    where T : class, IValidator<V>, new()
    where V : class, new()
{
    public static bool Validate(T t, V n)
    {
        T validator = new T(); 

        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(n);

        if (!results.IsValid)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Data Validation Checking Error:\n");

            foreach (var failure in results.Errors)
            {
                errorMessage.AppendLine("- " + failure.ErrorMessage);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.ToString(), "Exclamation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: CustomerValidator is not an abstract class. I've updated the question, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: it's not `IValidator<V>` but `AbstractValidator<V>` and on `Validate` method it just pass the V, anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign a `CustomerValidator` reference to a variable of type `T`. What if `T` is `StringBuilder` or something like that?

Fundamentally, it seems odd for your `ValidationHelper` to claim to be generic, but then be *specific* to `CustomerValidator`.

Without knowing about the FluentValidation library, we can't really know what `CustomerValidator` does - does it implement `Validator<Customer>` for example? It strikes me that you might want to pass the validator into the `Validate` method, or into the `ValidatorHelper` constructor. (I strongly suspect that you want to get rid of *both* of the static modifiers - if the method is static, it can't be implementing an abstract method in the base class... and if the class is static, it can't even specific a base class.)

Fundamentally, you need to consider:

- What should know about `CustomerValidator`? Probably *not* a generic helper class.
- What should create the validator? Options:

  - The helper itself (making use of the `new()` constraint, potentially)
  - The caller who creates an instance of the helper, assuming you're going to *have* an instance
  - Whatever calls your `Validate` method

You *may* want something like this:

```
// No constraint on V - why would you need one?
public class ValidatorHelper<T, V> : AbstractValidator<V> 
        where T : AbstractValidator<V>
{
    public bool Validate(T validator, V value)
    {
        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(value);

        if (!results.IsValid)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Data Validation Checking Error:\n");

            foreach (var failure in results.Errors)
            {
                errorMessage.AppendLine("- " + failure.ErrorMessage);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.ToString(), "Exclamation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is I want to make generic Validator, not limited only to CustomerValidator. It can be used to validate ProductValidator, SupplierValidator etc. I need V because it is the ViewModel as shown in this code: `ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(CustomerViewModel)`

Comment: @Willy: Okay, so your `V` is a `ViewModel` - what's the `T` meant to be? Basically it sounds like you need to think about the signatures of the methods a bit more carefully, along with what your type parameters are meant to mean.

Comment: The 'T' is a Validator class that inherit from `AbstractValidator`. As I said before, it can be CustomerValidator, SupplierValidator, ProductValidator etc. Sorry to make you confused :) this is the first time I try to implement generic pattern.

Comment: @Willy: Right, so the constraint I've put on in my code is probably appropriate. Now you need to think about what's going to create the validator, as I said in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet, I understand now, I solved the problem as written on my update